# Why does this ansible's conditional check keeps failing?

Tags: ansible

Why is the conditional check failing here?

```
  tasks:
  - name:
    command: dig @{{ item }} -t NS google.com
    with_items:
      - 4.5.6.7  # some server that fails
    register: dig_output

  - meta: end_play
    when: (dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout))
```

The error I get is this:

> ERROR! The conditional check '(dig_output|d('') == '') or
>   ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in
>   dig_output.results.0.stdout))' failed. The error was: error while
>   evaluating conditional ((dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('')
>   != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout))): Unable to
>   look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if
>   (dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR'
>   not in dig_output.results.0.stdout)) %} True {% else %} False {% endif
>   %}). Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters
>   like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable

If I just have the following, it actually passes if that helps in troubleshooting

```
  when: (dig_output|d('') == '') or ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout)
```

Wondering where my initial conditional is going wrong as individual parts of the whole seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as expected in Ansible 2.2.1.0. Here is a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - command: 'dig @{{item}} -t NS google.com +time=1'
      ignore_errors: yes
      with_items:
        - 4.5.6.7  # some server that fails
      register: dig_output

    - debug: var=dig_output.results.0.stdout

    - meta: end_play
      when: (dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout))

    - debug: var=dig_output.results.0.stdout
```

Output is:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
...ignoring
failed: [localhost] (item=4.5.6.7) => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["dig", "@4.5.6.7", "-t", "NS", "google.com", "+time=1"], "delta": "0:00:03.015272", "end": "2018-08-28 13:20:25.364956", "failed": true, "item": "4.5.6.7", "rc": 9, "start": "2018-08-28 13:20:22.349684", "stderr": "", "stdout": "\n; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> @4.5.6.7 -t NS google.com +time=1\n; (1 server found)\n;; global options: +cmd\n;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached", "stdout_lines": ["", "; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> @4.5.6.7 -t NS google.com +time=1", "; (1 server found)", ";; global options: +cmd", ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached"], "warnings": []}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dig_output.results.0.stdout": "\n; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Debian <<>> @4.5.6.7 -t NS google.com +time=1\n; (1 server found)\n;; global options: +cmd\n;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

The variable `dig_output.results.0.stdout` exists and the `when` expression of the `meta` tasks evaluates to `true`. The play ends and the second `debug` task gets omitted.

It works as long as `dig` fails. If the execution of `dig` itself fails (not installed), you get the error, you have quoted.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

    - command: 'gid @{{item}} -t NS google.com +time=1'
      ignore_errors: yes
      with_items:
        - 4.5.6.7  # some server that fails
      register: dig_output

    - debug: var=dig_output

    - meta: end_play
      when: (dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout))

    - debug: var=dig_output.results.0.stdout
```

Output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
...ignoring
failed: [localhost] (item=4.5.6.7) => {"cmd": "gid '' -t NS google.com +time=1", "failed": true, "item": "4.5.6.7", "msg": "[Errno 2] Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden", "rc": 2}

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "dig_output": {
        "changed": false, 
        "failed": true, 
        "msg": "One or more items failed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true, 
                "_ansible_no_log": false, 
                "_ansible_parsed": true, 
                "cmd": "gid '' -t NS google.com +time=1", 
                "failed": true, 
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "_raw_params": "gid @4.5.6.7 -t NS google.com +time=1", 
                        "_uses_shell": false, 
                        "chdir": null, 
                        "creates": null, 
                        "executable": null, 
                        "removes": null, 
                        "warn": true
                    }, 
                    "module_name": "command"
                }, 
                "item": "4.5.6.7", 
                "msg": "[Errno 2] Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden", 
                "rc": 2
            }
        ]
    }
}
ERROR! The conditional check '(dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout))' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ((dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout))): Unable to look up a name or access an attribute in template string ({% if (dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout)) %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}).
Make sure your variable name does not contain invalid characters like '-': argument of type 'StrictUndefined' is not iterable

The error appears to have been in '/home/szi/tmp/register.yml': line 15, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - meta: end_play
      ^ here
```

This means, before you dive into `dig_output.results.0`, you should check `dig_output.results.failed`:

```
when: dig_output.failed or (dig_output|d('') == '') or ((dig_output|d('') != '') and ('NOERROR' not in dig_output.results.0.stdout))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!